# Fixing horizontal space in resume

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I fix the part where it says "place of birth" in order to get it in the same line?

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
    \textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan (optional)
        \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{      % Same as \PersonalEntry
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value    

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
        \colorbox{Black}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{               % Same as \EducationEntry
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
        \colorbox{Black}{\color{White}#2} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par              % Company
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% you can upload a photo and include it here...
%\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
%   \vspace*{-2em}
%       \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{photo}
%\end{wrapfigure}

\MyName{Your Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae}

\sepspace

%%% Personal details
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Personal details}{}

\PersonalEntry{Place of Birth}{January 1, 1980}
\PersonalEntry{Address}{111 First St, New York}
\PersonalEntry{Phone}{(123) 000-0000}
\PersonalEntry{Mail}{\url{me@home.com}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example code is neither really minimal, nor does it match the output you show. Please fix that.

Comment: @leandriis DONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the definition of `\PersonalEntry`, a box named `\spacebox`is used for the first argument of the `\PersonalEntry` command. Its width ir originally defined as `\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}`. "Place of Birth"  is split into two lines, since it is wider than "8888888888". To overcome this, you can simply replace "8888888888"  with "Place of Birth"  or any different longer entry that you might want to add there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{Place of Birth}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\begin{document}

\PersonalEntry{Place of Birth}{January 1, 1980}
\PersonalEntry{Address}{111 First St, New York}

\end{document}
```